# How to check if somebody won in a tic tac toe gui game? (java)

Tags: java, user-interface, tic-tac-toe

I have basically everything in place to finish the tic tac toe game I've been working on, but am having trouble checking to see who won the game. Essentially, I'm trying to see if somebody won the game, and if they did, then to display a message saying which player won.

I've tried just brute-force checking every JButton row/column/diagonal but it doesn't seem to be working. I have the JButtons layed out in a 3 by 3 grid btw.

```
if((gameButton[0].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[1].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[2].getText().equals("X"))||
    (gameButton[3].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[4].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[5].getText().equals("X"))||
    (gameButton[6].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[7].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[8].getText().equals("X"))||
    (gameButton[0].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[3].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[6].getText().equals("X"))||
    (gameButton[1].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[4].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[7].getText().equals("X"))||
    (gameButton[2].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[5].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[8].getText().equals("X"))||
    (gameButton[0].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[4].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[8].getText().equals("X"))||
    (gameButton[2].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[4].getText().equals("X") && gameButton[6].getText().equals("X"))) {
        wonLabel.setText("Player X has won!");
    }

else if((gameButton[0].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[1].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[2].getText().equals("O"))||
    (gameButton[3].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[4].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[5].getText().equals("O"))||
    (gameButton[6].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[7].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[8].getText().equals("O"))||
    (gameButton[0].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[3].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[6].getText().equals("O"))||
    (gameButton[1].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[4].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[7].getText().equals("O"))||
    (gameButton[2].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[5].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[8].getText().equals("O"))||
    (gameButton[0].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[4].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[8].getText().equals("O"))||
    (gameButton[2].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[4].getText().equals("O") && gameButton[6].getText().equals("O"))) {
        wonLabel.setText("Player O has won!");
    }
```

I expected this to output a message of which player won, but when I interacted with the GUI and purposely made a certain row/column/diagonal either all "X" or "O", nothing happens. Any feedback/recommendations to make this more efficient would be welcome.

Comment: You should store it in a 3 by 3 matrix and then check diagonals. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352418/check-to-see-if-the-diagonal-wins-in-tic-tac-toe

Comment: Readability suggestion: You have some repeated code here (the `"X"` chunk and the `"O"` chunk.) Write a `private` method that will encapsulate this logic so you don't have to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest doing something like this, storing the text as a boolean array. After each time the button is pressed, set the point in the array to be true (if X) or false (if O). I'm going to assume that you already have a turn counter, with a boolean, it'll be referenced later.

Make sure that this boolean array is global!!!

```
boolean[3][3] check = new boolean[3][3];
```

In your actionEventListener having this run,

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
     Object source = e.getSource();
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
               if (source == board[i][j], turn == true){
                     check[i][j] = true;
               }
               else{
                     check[i][j] = false;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

After this, you can probably just have this method, which runs after each turn, or however you see fit.

```
private void win (){
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                int winO = 0;
                int winX = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) 
                {
                    if (check[i][j] == false)
                    {
                        winO++;
                        if (check[i+x][j+x] == false)
                        {
                            winO++;
                            System.out.println(winO);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (check[i][j] == true)
                    {
                        winX++;
                        if (check[i+x][j+x] == true)
                        {
                            winX++;
                            System.out.println(winX);
                        }
                    }
               if (winO == 4)
               {
                  wonLabel.setText("Player O has won!");
                  break;
               }
               else if (winX == 4)
               {
                  wonLabel.setText("Player X has won!");
                  break;
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fair warning. This only checks for diagonals! If you want to check for horizontal / vertical, you'll have to add the `x` value to `i` and/or `j` individually

There might be more efficient ways to do this, but this is the best I can do, hope it helps